# Number of matrices whose determinant is indivisible by a prime $p$

Tags: matrices, prime-numbers, combinations

> Let $p$ be an odd prime number and $T_p$ be the following set of $2 × 2$ matrices :
> $$T_p=\left\{A=\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&a\end{bmatrix};a,b,c \in \{0,1,2\cdots\cdots p-1\}\right\}$$
> Find $n(T_p)$ such that $p\nmid |A|$

The number of distinct elements in $T_p$ is $p^3$

Finding the number of matrices such that $p\mid |A|$:

Since $\Delta=a^2-bc$, let $kp=a^2-bc$

**Case 1)** $k=0 \implies a^2=bc$ leads to $p$ matrices($*$)

**Case 2)** $k>0$:

$$(a-\sqrt{bc})(a+\sqrt{bc})=kp$$

since $k<p$,

$$a-\sqrt{bc}=1,a+\sqrt{bc}=kp$$
or
$$a-\sqrt{bc}=k,a+\sqrt{bc}=p$$

Solving the two systems individually:

$$a=\frac{kp+1}{2},\sqrt{bc}=\frac{kp-1}{2}$$

$$a=\frac{p+k}{2},\sqrt{bc}=\frac{p-k}{2}$$

$k$ is strictly equal to $1$ for the first system and is odd for the second

$$a=\frac{p+1}{2},\sqrt{bc}=\frac{p-1}{2}$$

$$a=\frac{p+k}{2},\sqrt{bc}=\frac{p-k}{2}$$

I tried assuming $b=c$ to get rid of the square root, but couldn't justify it.

How do I proceed?

PS: [Similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3464568/let-p-be-an-odd-prime-number-and-t-p-be-the-following-set-of-2-%c3%97-2-matrice) has already been posted on MSE before, but I wish this to be answered separately.

($*$) There are more than $p$ cases, as pointed out in the comments

Comment: @JohnOmielan it seems like there are multiple posts and no, that isn't the one that I was referring to

Comment: Your approach is systematically wrong. You cannot conclude that either $a - \sqrt{bc} = 1$ or $a - \sqrt{bc} = kp$.

Comment: @MarkSaving Im not very good at number theory! Can you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: @MarkSaving Also, even earlier, for "Case 1", there are usually more than $p$ matrices with $a^2 = bc$.

Comment: @JohnOmielan You are right, there should be more.

Comment: Given $a$ and $b$, for how many $c$ is the determinant a multiple of $p$ ?

Comment: @Empy2 FYI, your question is the basis of this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/802799/602049) to [For how many values of $a,b,c\in(1,2\ldots,p-1)$ does $p$ | $({a^2}-bc)$ where $p$ is an odd prime number](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/802789/602049) (but keep in mind that $b = 0$ is special case).

Comment: @JohnOmielan yes! And I don't understand the answer given there...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $a=0$ then $b$ must lie in $1,\cdots,p-1$ and $c$ must lie in $1,\cdots,p-1$, for $-bc=|A|$ to not be divisible by $p$.  Thus we have $(p-1)^2$ possibilities.

On the other hand, if $a\neq 0$ then we have $p-1$ possibilities for $a$.  For each of these we have $p^2$ possible choices of $b,c$ in total, but we must discard all those where $p|a^2-bc$.

Given some fixed value of $a\neq 0$, from the $p^2$ possibilities for $b,c$, we wish to discard those combinations of $b,c$ which result in $p|a^2-bc$.  As $p$ does not divide $a^2$, the cases we discount are restricted to ones where $b\neq 0$.  There are then $p-1$ possible values of $b$ which may give rise to a matrix we wish to discount.

We claim that for each value of $b$, there is precisely one value of $c$, such that $p|a^2-bc$.

If we accept this claim then for each value of $a$, there are $p-1$ cases that need to be discounted, leaving $p^2-(p-1)$ values for $b,c$.  As there are $p-1$ non-zero values for $a$, we have

$$(p-1)(p^2-(p-1))$$ matrices with $a\neq 0$.

Thus in total we have $$(p-1)^2+(p-1)(p^2-(p-1))=p^3-p^2$$ possibilities.

---

Proof that if $a,b$ lie in $1,\cdots,p−1$, then there is a unique value of $c$ in $0,1,\cdots,p−1$ for which $p|a^2−bc$.

Fix $a,b$ as above.

Consider the map $f$ from the set of numbers $S=\{0,1,\cdots,p−1\}$ to itself, given by multiplication by $b$, followed by taking the remainder after division by $p$.

If $f(x)=f(y)$, then $bx$ and $by$ have the same remainder after division by $p$.  Thus $$p|bx-by=b(x-y).$$  As $p\nmid b$, we must have that $p|x-y$.  However as $x,y$ were both picked from $S$, they cannot differ by $p$ or more, so $x=y$.

Thus $f$ is injective.  As $f$ is a map from the finite set $S$ to itself, it must also be surjective (by the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle)).  Thus $f$ is a bijection.

Let $u$ be the remainder of $a^2$ after division by $p$.

There is a unique $c\in S$, such that $f(c)=u$.  In other words there is a unique $c\in S$ such that $bc$ and $a^2$ have the same remainder left, after they are both divided by $p$.

The numbers $a^2,bc$ having the same remainder after division by $p$, is the same as $p|a^2-bc$.

Comment: What is $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$? Also what do these specific cases that are to be discarded signify? I don't understand the point of $\frac{a^2}{b} \mod p$

Comment: I have written it in simpler terms now.  The answer depends on a claim that if $a,b$ lie in $1,\cdots,p-1$, then there is a unique value of $c$ in $0,1,\cdots,p-1$ for which $p|a^2-bc$.  I will add a justification for the claim, but first I want to check that everything else makes sense: That is you agree that if the claim is true, then there are $p^3-p^2$ matrices $A$ of the required form, with $p\nmid |A|$.

Comment: Thanks! Thats a lot easier to comprehend!! So to prove the claim, one must prove the existence and uniqueness of $c$ for every $a,b$, correct?

Comment: I have added an explanation for why we get existence and uniqueness of $c$.  Note the argument depends on $p$ being a prime number.

Comment: Thats a really clever proof!!